# Algebra simplification question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this? This is the LHS of the equation and I need it to equal the RHS, which is $2-1/k+!$

$$2−\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)2}$$

Comment: You should reduce to same denominator.

Comment: how do I go about this since k^2+k+1 is not factorable?

Comment: Just say that $2 = \frac{2k(k+1)}{k(k+1)}$, and simplify what you get in the numerator (where you should be able to factor out $k$).

Comment: Could you improve the formatting? The denominator of the LHS looks odd, and I have no idea what the RHS is what does "+!" mean?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656791/help-with-the-algebra-in-for-this-number-theory-proof?noredirect=1#comment1382262_656791

the second to last line in the first users answer. I don't understand how they went from the second to last line to the solution

Comment: That is not an equality, but an inequality. It just uses the fact that $k^2+k+1>k^2+k=k(k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

What was written in the question you reference is $$2-\{\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)^2}\}
\leq 2-\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}$$  Note that it is not an equality.  The numerator on the right expands to $k^2+k$, so the quantity being subtracted on the left is larger than the quantity being subtracted on the left.  This justifies the $\le$ sign, which could have been $\lt$